# mySQL Count distinct clients in a day

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'advice' in a mySQL database. The relevant fields are 'clientid' and 'advicedate'. I want to produce a table which lists each date and how many different clients have visited that day.

I have tried various queries including (from elsewhere in the Forum)

```
COUNT(DISTINCT clientid) AS ClnCount, advicedate FROM advice GROUP BY DATE(advicedate)
```

Which just gives one overall total and one date.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks fine to me other than your missing a select: works fine here: http://rextester.com/DGZ61628  `Select count(Distinct clientID), adviceDate from SO50391622_advice group by date(advicedate);`

Comment: Unable to recreate the problem. Please give us a working example of this problem with sample data, the query you're using, and expected output. From what I can see it should work (evidenced in rextester example above)

Comment: Thanks for this. From what I have read I would have thought it would work. I would want to get out a table with 2 columns - date and total - then for each date the number of different clients seen on each day. (Some are seen twice but would count once.)

Comment: Have you looked at the example link?http://rextester.com/DGZ61628  You're query should work.  Since I can't recreate it, I'm unable to figure out what's going on; thus I can't fix it.

Comment: The only way your query could be returning one date is if advicedate in your table has but one date; or if the group by portion wasn't running and mysql group by extensions were enabled. The group by would cause multiple dates to be listed if they existed, and if no group by was provided then the group by extensions of mysql would kick in causing it to "pick" a single date to display while getting a distinct count of all clients in the table.

Comment: I will try and get something online you can look at but it will be tomorrow I think. There are lots of dates - the table has over 2500 entries. I've used GROUP BY before and it has always worked as I expected it to so this is weird.

Answer (score -1):

Do not group by

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS
    SELECT count(Distinct clientID), advicedate 
    FROM advice
```

Comment: Reread the question: produce a table which lists EACH date and how many different clients have visited that day.

Comment: Not quite the update I was expecting; the LISTS EACH DATE and HOW MANY different clients have visited is what made me think  this was not in the correct approach

Comment: Screen shots, tabel and query are here - http://embold.co.uk/test/test.html